# A lot of transactions stuck in local node pool

Tags: txpool, invalid-opcode

Geth node does not release the transactions to pool. Transactions are stuck. When I realized this problem I saw there weas a new version. I updated Geth from 1.9.12 to 1.9.17 but the problem was not solved.

```
eth.pendingTransactions=[{
    blockHash: null,
    blockNumber: null,
    from: "0x0c333fd44e5447d99ab51fc8a2ee41dcc09fa4a4",
    gas: 21000,
    gasPrice: 12000000000,
    hash: "0x5c12ba7a7145e053f36eeb01521b9fcc4c61b1793d5efcbac52062c74d1be597",
    input: "0x",
    nonce: 14858,
    r: "0xc453f36a0cd1b946f7a53eb765cc8eaf409a2fadcd8d2eab6ba8ece4792d8d4c",
    s: "0x6a8f54f2b696e9dfeeaa328b9b13762e52e2179df3dc15fd8c04486ec61ebcd",
    to: "0x2f0728ab34de4a9f00e4e5e7593b8774acf35ba4",
    transactionIndex: null,
    v: "0x26",
    value: 2476212190000000000
}, {
    blockHash: null,
    blockNumber: null,
    from: "0x0c333fd44e5447d99ab51fc8a2ee41dcc09fa4a4",
    gas: 21000,
    gasPrice: 12000000000,
    hash: "0x9963dd5378c06292adecd33a1aa4975bd3c6195b9d11f132ff2a2481ac886b03",
    input: "0x",
    nonce: 14859,
    r: "0xcf8666d1867ca4b11ffedcde6c5771e9104d84d50a13a9f11463e9db6b9f406f",
    s: "0xfc1b88f00e4d0c2959ee0db47f342b7d187b765e9266794f70020dfb2db185",
    to: "0x8597375534a85ebc7631a2ad07f29a4ef4b1a529",
    transactionIndex: null,
    v: "0x26",
    value: 140000000000000000
}, {
    blockHash: null,
    blockNumber: null,
    from: "0x0c333fd44e5447d99ab51fc8a2ee41dcc09fa4a4",
    gas: 56209,
    gasPrice: 12000000000,
    hash: "0xf67f2201a1b4df4a30a80526f63b750c2276f16b7713c2e35d597381ca3e1de8",
    input: "0xa9059cbb0000000000000000000000009f50f7b83ff0f77adc1a215f7c2e58fae01a44f5000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001dcf87e0",
    nonce: 14860,
    r: "0x16bcd403bd556d140b33b94867dc42194d6d15d7dbd372128d33acb2ccf981d7",
    s: "0x5b1c830be601d15bb11ea462ed105a2c75062b66cf7f074f877df584fe137371",
    to: "0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7",
    transactionIndex: null,
    v: "0x25",
    value: 0
}, {
    blockHash: null,
    blockNumber: null,
    from: "0x0c333fd44e5447d99ab51fc8a2ee41dcc09fa4a4",
    gas: 42168,
    gasPrice: 146000000000,
    hash: "0x6378f43e0b0b16f585fa29852c1d959c65bf6aa31a242f750673f10870b58d82",
    input: "0xa9059cbb00000000000000000000000009942b2409079d9cb3b36dba8d6a60118e270746000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008aeaa9f6f9a900000",
    nonce: 14861,
    r: "0xf8b94056efcbfaf7bb9cc57f97f90bcad8eac773333cad0a7eb961cb4b56511c",
    s: "0x5b6a27e9563edcc9302a7038c03316cec7924a2e27a3fe2531ae936c1ca097c7",
    to: "0x3cc5eb07e0e1227613f1df58f38b549823d11cb9",
    transactionIndex: null,
    v: "0x26",
    value: 0
}, {
    blockHash: null,
    blockNumber: null,
    from: "0x0c333fd44e5447d99ab51fc8a2ee41dcc09fa4a4",
    gas: 21000,
    gasPrice: 73000000000,
    hash: "0xdf864819d6e965ffd721903b8c2a76311dca88e2342479e3a8dda8393ebe6a74",
    input: "0x",
    nonce: 14862,
    r: "0xb88c462726c2d5723df844f7a0aa46a0e9b57d0165be57bd02dab57cc52d93fd",
    s: "0x5e45ae4404449ac54e3342bb197a2e270bc0d8e70d85e96e4df577a9c26d7dfa",
    to: "0xda230dd23daa44d8522c7295f0770ae173f65a76",
    transactionIndex: null,
    v: "0x26",
    value: 3467000000000000
}, {
    blockHash: null,
    blockNumber: null,
    from: "0x0c333fd44e5447d99ab51fc8a2ee41dcc09fa4a4",
    gas: 42156,
    gasPrice: 76000000000,
    hash: "0x6ff731a01968b46a735f6194050582144634da689ae1adde6283463c87851c67",
    input: "0xa9059cbb000000000000000000000000da230dd23daa44d8522c7295f0770ae173f65a760000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000de0b6b3a7640000",
    nonce: 14863,
    r: "0xb497cd04a615ae5c9b1e3c23554e093c81b9c41c45421328534a360fa594c3cc",
    s: "0x15acb8cd464fadb9abcdafe29fdc3d57d84c367b366a7e2b8b364f592ba2b038",
    to: "0x3cc5eb07e0e1227613f1df58f38b549823d11cb9",
    transactionIndex: null,
    v: "0x25",
    value: 0
}]

txpool.status = {
  pending: 4598,
  queued: 521
}
eth.syncing=false
admin.peers.length=49
```

After the update, while  using 0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7 contract and run eth_estimateGas method I get "invalid opcode: opcode 0xfe is not defined" error.

RPC Request:

```
{"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0","params":[{"from":"0x0c333fd44e5447d99ab51fc8a2ee41dcc09fa4a4","to":"0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7","data":"0xa9059cbb0000000000000000000000009f50f7b83fF0f77aDc1a215f7c2e58FAE01a44f5000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001ddca740","value":"0x0","gasPrice":"0x215fbad300"}],"method":"eth_estimateGas"}
```

RPC Response:

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"error":{"code":-32000,"message":"invalid opcode: opcode 0xfe not defined"}}
```

Comment: Anybody have an idea?

Comment: If there is a lot of pending transactions the node will drop some of them because it doesn't have enough memory to hold all of them at the same time. That might cause future transactions to be stuck because a gap in the transactions nonces. The opcode 0xFE is the INVALID opcode it is by contracts when they reach an erroneous condition.

Comment: Okay thanks. This problem has been resolved.